# TCPDF with MySQL not printing table

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, export, tcpdf

I'm just trying to export a table from my page to PDF with TCPDF.

But it's only printing the header, not the table....

I already tried to remove all the TCPDF stuff and just echoed the statement, which works fine....

Anybody got an idea???

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$hostname = xxx
$db_user = xxx
$db_password = xxx
$database = xxx

$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($database,$db);

$sql = "    SELECT 
        p.`id`, p.`parent_id`, c.`name`, DATE_FORMAT(p.`date`, '%a %d.%m') as date, p.`text`, p.`images`, p.`platforms`, p.`link`, p.`topic`, p.`created`, p.`edited`
    FROM 
        `posts` p
    LEFT JOIN `customers` c     ON (p.`customer_id` = c.`id`)
    ORDER BY p.`date` ASC LIMIT 3;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

require_once('../../tcpdf/tcpdf_import.php');
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(L, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('xxx');
$pdf->SetTitle('xxx');
$pdf->SetSubject('xxx');
$pdf->SetKeywords('xxx');

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$tbl = "<h1>Posting Plan</h1>";
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');

$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$tbl .="<tr>
<td>".$row['id']."</td> 
<td>".$row['name']."</td>
<td>".$row['date']."</td> 
<td>".$row['text']."</td>
<td>".$row['images']."</td>
<td>".$row['platforms']."</td>
<td>".$row['link']."</td>
</tr>";
 }

$tbl .= '</table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

// ---------------------------------------------------------
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('xxx.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Here is the (working) test code:

```
<?php

$hostname = xxx
$db_user = xxx
$db_password = xxx
$database = xxx

$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($database,$db);

$sql = "    SELECT 
        p.`id`, p.`parent_id`, c.`name`, DATE_FORMAT(p.`date`, '%a %d.%m') as date, p.`text`, p.`images`, p.`platforms`, p.`link`, p.`topic`, p.`created`, p.`edited`
    FROM 
        `posts` p
    LEFT JOIN `customers` c     ON (p.`customer_id` = c.`id`)
    ORDER BY p.`date` ASC LIMIT 3;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0" border="1">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$tbl .="<tr>
<td>".$row['id']."</td> 
<td>".$row['name']."</td>
<td>".$row['date']."</td> 
<td>".$row['text']."</td>
<td>".$row['images']."</td>
<td>".$row['platforms']."</td>
<td>".$row['link']."</td>
</tr>";
 }

$tbl .= '</table>';

echo $tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer;

?>
```

Comment: You have absolutely zero error handling in there, and are simply assuming your query actually succeeded and returned a non-empty result set. Never assume success. always check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: i tested my query by removing all pdf stuff & echo $tbl. works properly

Comment: just edited the question with the working test code

Comment: Have you tried to save the whole table with heading, header, body and footer in _$tbl_ and then use _writeHTML_ only once?